# iPhone SDK: How to get the selected tabitem on a tabbar?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have this code
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item

What I am looking for is a code snippet that illustrates how to detect which button was pressed inside the delegate presumably using item.

So maybe I have buttons 1 - 4 lined up on the tabbar. My user presses the button position 2. I need to know that so I can bring up a view appropriate for that button.

I tried something like this but it is not working.

```
NSInteger *barIndex = [[barTab items] IndexofObject:item];
```

If someone could provide some working example code that would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

when you create your `UITabBarItem`s you'll want to give them each a specific tag. When your `- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item` method is called, read the tag number out.

```
NSInteger tag = item.tag;
```

Using the index of the item is not appropriate for tab bars, since the user can change the order of the tabs.

---

And good practice is to use an enum for each of your tags, so that you don't have a bunch of "random" numbers scattered throughout your code.

```
typdef enum {
  JPButton1,
  JPButton2,
  JPButton3
} JPButtonType
```

and then in your `tabBar:didSelectItem:` method you can test the tags like so:

```
if (item.tag == JPButton1) {
  // do some stuff with button one here
}
```

Comment: careful with my syntax on the addition. i don't have any compilers handy, so I'm not 100% that it's correct, but it should be plenty close.

Answer (score 3):

I realize this question is quite old, but maybe this will help someone in the future:

The *UITabBarController* has a property called *selectedIndex*.
For example, if the *UITabBarController* is declared as *myTabBar*,
you can always get the currently selected tab index by calling

```
[myTabBar selectedIndex]
```

it will be equal to 0 for the first tab, 1 for the second, and so on...

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is over to years old now but you were on the right line instead of using

```
NSInteger *barItem = [[tabBar items] indexOfObject:item];
```

you need to use

```
int barItem = [[tabBar items] indexOfObject:item];
```

This is because

```
indexOfObject:item
```

will return an int not an NSInteger.